# Android Studio got very slow and constantly "updating indices"

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, gradle

There are more similar question on the SO, but I haven't found my answer on any of them so I am opening new one.

I am using:

Android Studio 2.2.3 (but was same with the 2.2.2)
Gradle 2.14.1 
JRE 1.8.0

I am using it on the mac, OS X El Capitan (2.5 GHz, i5, 8GB RAM).

It has been working great until few weeks ago, and now it is so painfully slow. Most of the time it is **"indexing/updating indices"**.

I am not that concerned about build time (it takes about 30-40sec, but I can live with that) as much as that constant indexing that makes coding almost impossible (overall responsiveness is pretty poor).

Is there anything in my gradle files that could cause this?

I do have some dependencies, but the app itself is relatively simple.

build.gradle //app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myproduct"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
}
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.+'

    compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.4'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.10'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1'
}
```

build.gradle//project

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

       }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

P.S. 
I have enabled - offline work, parallel and daemon. I have increased VM heap size. I have uploaded to latest Android Studio. I have replaces maven with jcenter().
Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: It could be your machine, the machine at my workplace is terrible so i run Android Studio and SDK components through an external HDD and it runs as fast as you'd like now, you could try turning automatic updates off too.

Comment: My working pc taked 5 min to build, but since coding is ok so I guess the problem might be on imports or dunno. a few questions: you have everything updated from the update center? have you tried recompiling all project so it load everything needed?

Comment: yes, I have done that few times during last week, very strange..

Comment: You can try to invalidate caches and restart. The index should run once.
Did you add new folders in your project ? If they change, a new indexing process start, so a folder with generated code for example can do this knid of thing.

Comment: I have tried to do that also several times.

Comment: Where is your project located? Sometimes it updates indices when file changes or any existing file system call.

Comment: And this problem is still happening in year 2018 to version 3.1.4.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the others having the same problem:

My android studio returned back to its original performance (which was ok). 
It is hard to me to say what made an improvement because I have done lots of changes at once, here are few I recall:

- replaced maven with -> jcenter()
- set flag in properties to use **default gradle wrapper**
- updated android studio to latest version (at the moment 2.2.3)
- enabled gradle daemon - Configuration On Demand
- invalidate cache and restart(few times)

some of it I have tried before asking this question, but I think all came back to normal when I did last update to Android studio 2.2.3

Answer (score 51):

It also happened to me,I just **Sync 'app'** and it was solved...

Or use this

**Invalidate Caches / Restart under "File Menu"**

Comment: Invalidate Caches / Restart solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: What is it updating on earth? Why does it take so much time, over and over again?

Comment: @Leon must be some bug

Comment: I tried this and ran `./gradlew clean` just to make sure everything cleared.

Comment: I tried 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' and it made no difference for me. (Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2)

What is 'sync app'?

Answer (score 19):

Also, you can try:

Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

This worked for me.

Comment: Hi Rafael, this question is already answered, and your solution has already been added in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Try to store Sdk on other drive and also try to invalidate cache and restart.
Hope this helps

Comment: I am already storing the SDK on a portable drive. But it doesn't help me.

Comment: what is your pc configuration?

Comment: 128 GB SSD, 12 GB RAM, i3 4th Gen Processor.

Answer (score 6):

I just deleted the .idea folder and restarted Android Studio then I pressed button "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

[image]

and everything goes fine.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Invalidate Caches / Restart solved my problem.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem with Android Studio 4.0.1. Pressing the `sync button` like suggested  in the top answer didn't solve the problem. It actually created a second loop. And I didn't want to `invalidate the caches`.

However I solved it easy by just `restarting Android Studio`.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of constant "updating indices" issues by increasing the max heap size of Android Studio process.

To do so, [change Studio's JVM options](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config) (Help -> Edit Custom VM Options...) to include `-Xmx2g` where `2g` is the amount of memory enough to keep Studio happy with your project complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Then on the dialog that opens select "Invalidate and Restart"

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Removing gradle caches is work in my case.

```
rm -rf /User/user/.gradle/caches
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, but only when having multiple 'packages' under *'app/java/com.example.projectname'*
If you have multiple packages within your java folder, try this. It worked instantly for me.

In Android Studio's 'Project Window,' right click on *'app/java/com.example.android.projectname'* then click 'Show in Explorer.' Move all of your '.java' files out of their sub-folder and place them all in the 'app/java/com.example.android.projectname' folder.

Next, go back into Android Studio and open up all of your '.java' files. At the top of your code you should see `package com.example.android.projectname.subfolder;`
Because you've removed the 'packages' and relocated the '.java' files, you need to change every '.java' file's package to read `package com.example.android.projectname;`

You'll also need to go into the manifest and change *'activity android:name=...'*

Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was a broken module, that had some weird kind of symlinks that caused indexing of all files in `/usr/local`, which resulted not only in long indexing, but also in a enormous caches created.

Simply unloading the module helped. Cmd+Shift+A (Search everything) and look for "Load/unload modules". Unload all modules you don't need. Restart IDE (invalidating caches might also help further) and problem with endless indexing should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes invalidate caches donot work the way it's expected.

In that case, you should restart your machine.